# Why 'y' shows two different values in the below alert cases?

Tags: javascript, operators, logical-operators

Consider the below code:

```
var y = 4;
alert( y>1 || (y++ ===4)) 
alert(y);
```

Here, 'y' alerts 4.
But in the below code:

```
var y = 4;
alert( y>1 && (y++ ===4)) 
alert(y);
```

Here, 'y' alerts 5. 
Why && and || operators are showing two different values of 'y'?

Comment: `||` only evaluates the second operand if the first operand is falsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:

> false && (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to false.
>
> true || (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to true.

That is In case of `|| (or)` operator the second condition is not checked if first evaluates to true where as in case of `&&(and)` operator the second condition is not checked if first evaluates to false.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you are shortcutting the execution:

```
y>1  // This is already true
||
(y++ ===4) // So this is not executed
```

Answer (score 2):

In an OR conditional statement, if the first condition passes, the subsequent condition is not checked, which is where the value of y is incremented.

AND conditionals work in reverse. If the first condition is false, then the subsequent condition will not be checked.

You didn't ask about it, but it might also be worth noting that
`y++ === 4`
Will increment the value of y *after* it is compared to 4. So then when the next statement is executed, the value of y has been incremented to 5, even though when it was compared to 4 it was 4. If you had wanted to compare the incremented value of y to 4, then incrementing first is done `++y === 4`. This will increment and *then* do the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer here is "because skipping redundant processing makes programs run faster".

Compiler/interpreter designers are always on the lookout for little optimizations like this that will make programs in their language run faster.

Logical `OR` (`||`) evaluates until it hits the first `true` condition or until it finds that all conditions were `false`. Once the `OR` hits the first `true` condition, no other conditions can change the fact that the `OR` will eventually evaluate to `true`, so why bother executing them?

For the same reason, logical `AND` (`&&`) evaluates until it hits the first `false` condition (or finds that all conditions were `true`).

Languages that always execute all the conditions in a boolean logic sequence are exceedingly uncommon; you should *expect* `AND` and `OR` to act this way in the next language you learn.

In your example, this means the interpreter found that `y>1` in the `OR` test was true, so it immediately skipped the rest of the conditions, including the postincrement (`++`).
The first *and* second `AND` conditions were executed (because the first was `true`, and `AND` only stops on `false`).

Note that if you start with `y = 1` then the `OR` *will* increment `y`, but your `AND` *won't*.

You should order your `OR` conditions such that it will find `true` soonest, and your `AND` conditions should be ordered to find `false` soonest, where "soonest" means whatever logical path gets you to the answer with the least processing.